# Why is the animation behavior different between Webkit and Gecko?

Tags: html, css

This will only animate the top element in Gecko, but Webkit will animate both elements. Why did this difference occur?

When I check the CSS3 spec, Firefox works correctly. Are other specifications related to the cause of this difference?
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-origin

```css
h1 {
  animation: animation1 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    color: blue;
  }
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}

h1+h1 {
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<h1>heading1</h1>
<h1>heading2</h1>
```

Comment: it's probably a bug

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thank you. Is there a mistake in my understanding that Firefox is technically correct and Chrome is buggy? Do you know if there are bug tickets?